# Xamarin c# missing packages?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I cannot seem to import the Vector3D or Point3D in my program that I am writing. It doesn't seem to find System.Windows.Media.Media3D. Does Xamarin not contain this package? What would my alternative be if I cannot use the Media3D package?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  Media3d is a WPF dll and is not available on mobile.

Comment: It would be great if WPF was cross-platform. It would actually eliminate and all other UI frameworks / languages including HTML and whatever crappy java stuff, but it's Windows only, therefore unavailable in mobile platforms such as Android or iOS.

Comment: Nooooooo... So I can't use it. I guess I'll have to search for a 3D party library or write my own stuff. Ah, that's annoying.

Comment: I know on non-Windows environments, Xamarin requires Mono (I'm not sure about Windows machines). Please check the [Mono Compatibility Page](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) to see if your library falls under one of the unsupported sections. This is just speculation, but if it's incompatible with Mono, then I could see it  potentially being incompatible with Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If these are the only two class missing: `Point3D` and `Vector3D`? Can you just write your own? They should be pretty straightforward.

Another option is to use the implementation of Vector3 from MonoGame found [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Vector3.cs).

However, if you are using all kinds of classes in WPF, you are going to be up a creek. There is equivalent functionality on iOS and Android for the user interface in most cases, but you will have to rewrite your code using Apple/Android APIs.